# How can Rackhir and Elric exist in the same universe?

Tags: eternal-champion, elric-saga

According to Multiverse.org, both Rackhir and Elric are incarnations of the Eternal Champion. They both clearly exist in Elric's universe, as Rackhir appears several times without any cosmic interference (as when the Three Who Are One appear). However, Jhary-a-Conel mentions that it's dangerous for incarnations to meet one another when, in *The Sleeping Sorceress*, Elric, Erekosë, and Corum unite.

(from *The Sleeping Sorceress*, Book 3, Chapter 5)

> "It will suit me," Erekosë said. "I will remain with Elric. Then, perhaps..."
>
> A look almost of terror spread over Jhary's features then. He said sadly: "My friend--already much of time and space is threatened with destruction. Eternal barriers could soon fall--the fabric of the multiverse could decay. You do not understand. Such a thing as has happened in the Vanishing Tower can only happen once or twice in an eternity and even then it is dangerous to all concerned.["]

Worth noting is that Aubec (another incarnation) also appears in this universe, but seems to appear prior to the events of the Elric stories (hence why Elric has his sword in *Elric of Melniboné*). But this is a case in which two incarnations seem to exist in the same universe, at the same time, and interact with one another regularly.

So, how is that possible (within the realm of Moorcock's Multiverse)?

Answer (score 4):

With a sprawling, multifaceted backdrop like Moorcock's Multiverse, it's hard to keep track of all the details. Something that's true for one character may not be for another, and what's true in one place may not be in another.

For instance, when Jhary-a-Conel says it's dangerous to have several champions together, what does he mean? The most likely answer is that they will combine to deal with some threat and, drunk with power, refuse to disengage. This is presented as a real possibility, at least with Corum (see *The King of Swords*).

On the other hand, from Elric's perspective at least, that experience is repugnant. In addition, one can hardly imagine several such strong-willed personalities working together so closely for any length of time. When not fighting, the champions regard each other with bemused tolerance. There's no hint that their very proximity has an effect on the fabric of spacetime. Jhary's warning may be preemptive, planting a seed of doubt where there had been none.

Let's assume, though, that Jhary is correct. He seems to know more than he ever admits.

It's established that a single universe has a single champion. Rackhir must come from some other realm, and he's visited many others. By the time he meets Elric in Tanelorn, he is ready to find a home. It's possible that his attachment to his own universe has rubbed off, so he avoids the perils of proximity. It's possible that the impending Conjunction has already destabilized the multiverse, so any damage the two champions could do is negligible. It's possible that Rackhir is a special case or comes from a realm so distant that the problem never arises. It's possible that some places are vulnerable to this effect, while others are not. It's even possible that, because this hazard would interfere with the plot, it's not even acknowledged.

Comment: Rackhir is a former Warrior Priest from Phum, in the East, past Elwher. Prior to being exiled to Ameeron, he was familiar with the likes of Moonglum, thus, he's a contemporary of Elric. Moonglum recognizes him as well, so we can't assume it's a parallel Moonglum in a universe in which Rackhir is the EC.

Answer (score -1):

Jhary-a-Conel's statement is merely that it is dangerous for multiple incarnations to exist in the same universe and at the same time; this doesn't deny the *possibility* that it may happen.

This is supported by text at another source, http://stormbringer.wikia.com/wiki/Eternal_Champion, which states:

> It is possible for multiple aspects of the Champion to exist in the same universe, though it is dangerous and risks damaging the Multiverse.

There is therefore no problem with this.

Comment: You know the deal by now, you can go [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) to merge accounts and collect all your reputation.

Comment: True, but Jhary also said it's not a good idea ("Such a thing that happened in the Vanishing Tower can only happen once or twice in an eternity and even then it is dangerous to all concerned." *The Sleeping Sorceress* chapter 5). That indicates a problem, to me.

Comment: book 3, chapter 5, that is.

Comment: That appears to be a fan-written wiki. Can you offer any better evidence?